# How much training did the Force ghosts give Luke?

Tags: star-wars, force-ghost

At the end of *Return of the Jedi* we see the Force ghosts associated with Luke.

[image: Three ghostly blue figures stand on endor, in traditional jedi robes; Anakin, Yoda and Obi-Wan Kenobi]

Do any of these ghosts give Luke training either physical or otherwise?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why couldn't Qui-Gon Jinn's Force ghost warn Yoda when Anakin killed the Tusken Raiders?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10580/2565)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe in the Thrawn trilogy it's mentioned he never spoke to Force Ghost Yoda or Force Ghost Anakin.

I seem to recall Force Ghost Kenobi giving subtle guidance, such as directing him to places (e.g. the Jedi temple on Yavin IV in  [The Lost City of the Jedi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_City_of_the_Jedi)) or giving warnings like in [The Truce at Bakura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truce_at_Bakura).

Comment: They are presences that help guide but they do not give training and can only impart brief messages.

Comment: @Chad - sorry, but you are wrong. Qui-Gon's ghost taught the whole Force Ghost thing to both Yoda and presumably Obi-Wan

Comment: @DVK - Actually Qui-Gon shared the technique with Yoda before he died.  And presumably appeared after his death to guide Yoda.  Though I have not seen the actual after appearance in the story anywhere.

Comment: In ESB, after Yoda's death, Obi Wan's ghost has a long and articulated conversation with Luke, and he behaves just like a living person. I've always found funny the fact that he even sits down on a rock, slowly and with some effort, like he still was in his old body.

Comment: Maybe he was having to concentrate to sit ON the rock.  Who knows how difficult it might be for a ghost to interact, or at least appear to interact, with matter.

Comment: I remember that Obi-Wan's ghost stuck around Luke for a few years, I think it was 4 or 5 years, guiding him and telling him about various things. He finally moves on after telling Luke that he's not the last Old Jedi, but rather the first of the New. I vaguely remember this from one of the books... must've been one in the Thrawn trilog (or 'Leia's wedding' x_X)

Answer (score 1):

In *The Last Jedi*, Force Ghost Yoda visits Luke on Ahch-To, shortly before

> Luke's death and subsequent transformation into a Force Ghost himself.

In this case, he doesn't seem to provide *training* per se, but more general encouragement and mentorship to help him understand that

> Rey is or will become a Jedi and that Luke still has a part to play.